# How should I parse keywords when writing a C Compiler?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, lexer

I am currently in the process of writing a C to Assembly compiler, it is not meant to be practical, but I would like to do it for the educational value. I was wondering when I am testing for keywords, is there any more efficient way rather than just reading in the next word in the file and then running it through a bunch of nested if statements that test for the keywords. Is there any better way?

Comment: You can try perfect hashing, but it's unlikely that this phase is going to be your performance bottleneck.

Comment: I change the tag [parsing] to [scanning]. Identifying individual tokens is done by the first phase of the compiler, the scanner, and not by the second phase, the parser.

Comment: And now I noticed that [scanning] is the wrong tag. Changed it again, to [lexer].

Comment: You fall victim to the "No premature optimization" principle. There's nothing wrong with searching the sorted list of keywords with bsearch(). Even a linear search may only be negligibly slower. Testing code for tokens in a C like language is never a bottleneck. You are waaaay overthinking this little problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is actually quite specific. You are asking about how to build the lexical analyzer, also known as the scanner, and how to efficiently and conveniently recognize keywords. The scanner is the first phase of a typical compiler, and it converts the source code, which is a sequence of characters, to a sequence of tokens, where a token is a unit such as a number, an operator or a keyword.

Since keywords match the pattern for general identifiers, a common trick is to put all the keywords in the symbol table, together with information that it is a keyword. Then, when the scanner finds an identifier, it as usual searches the symbol table to see if that identifier has been seen before. If this identifier was a kewyord, it will be found, together with the information about which keyword it is.

Answer (score 4):

Are you doing this for part of a class? If so, there should be guidelines on parsing and lexing. If not, you're in for a lot of work!

Writing an actual compiler is much more complicated than just going through a bunch of if statements, because you need to keep track of the environment. You'll need to think about how you allow classes, functions, function calls, class instantiations, recursive functions... the list goes on.

Take a look at course lectures from UC Berkeley on the subject, i.e. parsing, lexing, code generation, and the tools you'll need:

http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs164/fa13/

Note that this course in particular used C++ to write a Python2.5 to Assembly compiler, but the concepts in the Lectures and Readings and some of the tools are not language-restricted.

Answer (score 3):

Keywords (instead of tokens in general) is a closed set, for which it's practical to generate a collision free hash function. Because the set is small, it's not even necessary to have a minimum hash function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a bunch of if - else if statements and strcmp(). However, writing statements for all of the keywords gets annoying very quickly. You'd be better off using a hash table - at the start of the compilation you put all keywords in the table and then you do lookups as needed. The drawback of this is that if you have to use C, you'll also have to write your own hash table (or use one from a library). If you can use C++, though, then you can use a map or an unordered_map from the STL. In any case, if you are worried about the performance, as someone else mentioned, it won't be a bottle neck.